# How do I use a specific class based on the selected tab in a TabControl?

Tags: c#, winforms, class, tabcontrol

I have a TabControl with the TabPages named `foo`,`bar`, abd `baz` in the Main form. When a user changes to the `bar` tab I want it to use the code in the `bar.cs` class, when a user changes to the `baz` tab, I want to run the code in the `baz.cs` class, etc. Kind of like an "all-in-one" form in the sense that it has multiple different functionalities but I don't want all the code to be in one single class.

How can I achieve this? Is this even the proper way of doing something like this?

Comment: Doubtful, TabControl was made to organize UI, not to select classes.  Don't use TabControl when you need RadioButtons.  Use a delegate if you think you're doing it right anyway.

Comment: It can be done, should it, no. Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Just use UserControls, one for each separate tab.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking to break up the code so you don't have one enormous Form then a standard approach is to break the contents of each tab page out into a custom User Control (a reusable composite control).

1. In Visual Studio, add a new item to your project and select "User Control".
2. Use the designer to add whatever controls/logic/events/properties you want.
3. Build your project. After the build is complete, you should see your new UserControl in the VS Toolbox, probably near the top.
4. Drag your control onto the desired TabPage in your Form. Set its Dock property to Full so it fills the tab control.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm not understanding the question, but it seems rather straightforward to me that you can subscribe to the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, instantiate the appropriate class, and run the code.

```
private void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (myTabControl.SelectedTab.Name)
    {
        case "foo":
        {
            var o = new foo();
            o.RunCode();
            break;
        }
        case "bar":
        {
            var o = new bar();
            o.RunCode();
            break;
        }
        case "baz":
        {
            var o = new baz();
            o.RunCode();
            break;
        }

    }
}
```